# Spark - partitioned parquet - query distinct values on partition key takes a lot of time

Tags: apache-spark, distinct, parquet, partition

I have a parquet partitioned by a date field "dt" in S3 (in my parquet's base directory, there are multiple "dt=" subdirectories).

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://my_s3_bucket/my_parquet_location/")
distinctDates = df.select("dt").distinct()
distinctDates.explain(True)
```

The execution plan had been quickly derived, with 796 partitions found:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Deduplicate [dt#310]
+- Project [dt#310]
   +- Relation[,... 287 more fields] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
dt: date
Deduplicate [dt#310]
+- Project [dt#310]
   +- Relation[<>,... 287 more fields] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [dt#310], [dt#310]
+- Project [dt#310]
   +- Relation[<>,... 287 more fields] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[dt#310], functions=[], output=[dt#310])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(dt#310, 200)
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[dt#310], functions=[], output=[dt#310])
      +- *(1) FileScan parquet [dt#310] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://my_s3_bucket/my_parquet_location], PartitionCount: 796, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>
```

Now when I tried to count the number of entries in my distinctDates dataframe:

```
distinctDates.count()
```

It takes many minutes to execute before giving the result "796".

That's strange. I don't understand what Spark is doing with my query. Did I do something wrong? For queries on partition keys, I would expect to get the results instantly.

Comment: i dont understand how u r expecting thigs to be instantaneous?  for the distinct u didnt give any criteria --remember this.

Comment: Hi Ravi. Sorry, I dont get what you meant in "give any criteria". The distinct() is called after select(dt), which means I am looking for all possible values of dt, which basically should be same as listing all possible partitions. That listing of all partitions could be done in a few ms when Spark calculates the execution plan.

Comment: `give any criteria` -->i meant give some filter condition to take advantage of partitions, if any. OK make sure that u have big chunks of ORC files. avoid fragmentation of the files being read/ scanned. Try putting the original files on HDFS to see if s3 is the reason for the slowness. --btw, sorry for the late reply back

Comment: Hi @Averell did you specify a "basePath" option so the "dt" column corresponds to the partition ?

Comment: Hi @baitmbarek, Sorry I missed your message. I tried with and without having that "basePath" option but I could see no difference. Also I could see that in the plan, "PushedFilters: []" is an empty array. Not sure whether that's something wrong